# Tridion caching metrics

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, cache

I am playing with various caching options, including JMS, in the CD storage config. And I found the logging (`com.tridion.cache`). Until now to get info on whether a request is served from cache or by lookup in the broker storage I have to start a debug session and trace.

Is there any way to get a log or stats on how often Tridion CD serves from cache v.s. from broker storage?

Comment: Don't have reputation enough to comment.
This is probably not relevant for you Jan, but because you mention JMS and that logging have stopped. I want to share my experience. When I have used JMS cache togheter with Apache MQ, there is a conflict between CD-jars (2013 sp1) and the Apache MQ jar, with the result that you don't get any logging at all from CD as long as you have the Apache MQ jar in the lib-directory.

Comment: It is not an answer to my question indeed, nevertheless still an interesting finding. How did you solve this?

Comment: If I remember Support had some sort of work around, but we never tried that out. We are running without Tridion logging in CD. Instead we have our own logging in our web apps. If we need to log CD, we have to turn of JMS cache and remove jar-file to get the CD-logs.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the single full apachemq jar in deployer and website bin\lib folder, copy the individual jars from apachemq installation lib except log4j jar. After doing that the logging will start working on the application.